# Reflection TargetInvocationException error when charging DLL dynamically

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to load a DLL dynamically so I can compare two identical methods from different DLL version,  without using Web-services.

I already did that on an other project, and it worked perfectly.

But the Dll I need to import is more complex now, it uses C++ dll reference etc.

Here is the part of code :

```
            Type type1 = dll1.GetType("MyNamespace.MyClass");
            var instance1 = Activator.CreateInstance(type1, "some string", "some string", "some string");


            MethodInfo myMethod1 = type1.GetMethods().Where(X => X.Name == "myMethod").FirstOrDefault();
            object retour1 = (object)myMethod1.Invoke(instance1, new object[] { fichier.FullName, dossier.FullName, null, false, null });
```

The last line of code return a "**System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException**"
apperently in "mscorlib.dll"

Since I am quite new to reflection, I do not really know what is happening, is this because of c++ dll, or did i forget something? The same code works on simpler DLL.

Maybe there is a better way to do this task, but as I cannot do the following :

```
Using myLib
Using myLib
```

I am stuck, any help would be very appreciated =)

Comment: Please post the full exception aswell as the trace.

Comment: This is doomed to fail for non-trivial scenarios, because you're assuming that those differently-versioned DLLs will not have conflicting dependencies (i.e. version X wants version X of `dependency.dll` while version Y wants version Y). If the DLLs actually depend on a C or C++ runtime, things get exponentially more complicated, since having different versions of that runtime loaded in one process is either not supported at all or comes with severe caveats. You don't need to go full web service, but at some point you'll probably have to bite the bullet and use different processes.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Apperently dll file was not suffisant, thanks for pointing me "conflict" , that lead me to the idea of charging all other dll dependencies. So I copy/paste all other references and the error no longer occurs. I know this is not a proper code, but it is just for internal benchmark so it is not a big deal.

Comment: If you're only ever going to load one single version of the DLL in the process (albeit dynamically) there is no problem, and if you want a representative benchmark, that's what you probably should do anyway (because things like JIT warmup, allocated memory and caching influence the times, so the second method you call would not have the same characteristics as the first one unless you take proper precautions). I don't know the rest of your benchmark code, but I'm going to recommend the use of [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) anyway.